# Change NavBarTitle on SystemColor change

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationview, uinavigationbarappearance

Good day everyone,

I was trying to change the `titleTextAttributes` of the `UINavigationBar.appearance()` depending on the actual SystemColor (.dark, .light)

First of all I used an initializer to change the `.foregroundColor`, everything works fine.
Additionally I want to automatically get it changed depending on light- or darkmode using `colorScheme`.
This works fine on a button I added into the NavBar:

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        showingAddView.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Label("Hinzufügen", systemImage: "plus.circle").foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white : Color.black)
                    }
```

Now I have the problem not knowing how to solve that for UI Components...
I tried integrating `colorScheme` like this:

```
init() {
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = colorScheme == .dark ? [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white] : [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = colorScheme == .dark ? [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white] : [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
            }
```

But it didn't work

Does anybody know how to use `colorScheme` or any other modifier to achieve this?
Thank you all in advance!

Greetings Marcel

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
```

Does this help you?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer!
I already integrated that, thats why my button works fine but I can't figure out how to use it on the navigationView title!